# Android Java make bitmapfactory images clickable

Tags: java, android

Alright so how can I do this..

I have 2 classes

PlayActivity.java
and
Play.java

PlayActivity's setContentView is play.java

In play.java I have this:

```
gBall1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
gBall3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall5 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
gBall6 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall7 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
gBall8 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
gBall9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall10 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
gBall11 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall12 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mantrans);
gBall13 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.womentrans);
```

And these appear on the screen..

How exactly can I make them clickable and show a toast?

Answer (score 0):

You should set these bitmaps to an imageview and add a setOnClickListener to the imageview.

That way the images can be clicked on.

Comment: In my thing i have them scroll down a straight line so i can't do that with imageviews. http://pastebin.com/SkUNBErL  <-- thats my code that makes them scroll and etc

Comment: Take the whole view in scrollView or create them as imageView and put it linear layout and put it inside the scrollview. make the linearlayout vertical oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise here is that, in android, only a view is clickable. In your case the individual Bitmaps are contained is a View and therefore if a click listener can be applied to anything it has to be done on the View itself. i:e a bitmap cannot to made clickable unless it is put inside a view (ImageView in this case).

Therefore i suggest you make your Play class extend a Layout like FrameLayout or LinearLayout. Then add all the bitmaps to ImageViews and add the imageviews to the class.

```
 this.addView(childImageView)
```